# VIM - Sort on third column - Uneven spacing

Tags: regex, sorting, vim

I am trying to sort some blocks of code in vim on the third column in some function protocols. I've tried using the external `sort` command via `sort -n -k3`, but it seems that this program assumes there are no consecutive delimiters, and fails.

eg:

```
static int test(int a, int b);
static char toChar(uint8_t i);
static char plusChar(uint8_t i);
static int test2(int a, int b);
static bool testBool(bool b);
```

I first pipe this through column via `%!column -t`, and I get some relatively useful output:

```
static  int   test(int          a,   int  b);
static  char  toChar(uint8_t    i);
static  char  plusChar(uint8_t  i);
static  int   test2(int         a,   int  b);
static  bool  testBool(bool     b);
```

The first problem is that I only want the first few columns spaced. So, I have to manually alter the table to become (tediously):

```
static int   test(int a, int b);
static char  toChar(uint8_t i);
static char  plusChar(uint8_t i);
static int   test2(int a, int b);
static bool  testBool(bool b);
```

Now, the second half of the problem is sorting the above results to become:

```
static char  plusChar(uint8_t i);
static int   test(int a, int b);
static int   test2(int a, int b);
static bool  testBool(bool b);
static char  toChar(uint8_t i);
```

So, in short, is there a relatively simple regex to achieve the column-ization of the code, and then sort it on the third column? I figured for the first part, something like `s/static \S+\s+`, but I can't figure out how to make the entire string a fixed width. As for the second part, I tried using the built-in VIM regex `%sor r /static \S+\s+.+$/`, but it doesn't sort at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need programmatic methods to achieve this since you need to check whether or not each "element" in each "column" has a shorter length than the largest one in the same "column" in order to determine the number of spaces to replace each single space with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about first doing the sort, then lining things up nicely?  I can help with the first step:

```
:sort / .\{-} /
```

See `:help :sort` for details.  (Note that there are two spaces in the pattern I gave.)

Comment: That actually solves the second part, even if I don't do the initial column-ization. Thanks. Can you explain what the regex means a bit? I read it as "space, any single character, UNKNOWN, space". What does the `{-}` mean? I am only familiar with hyphens when used to determine a range in a storage class, ie: `[A-Z]`, between brackets, not when between braces.

Comment: Vim's `\{-}` is a non-greedy match, think `*?` in Perl. You can learn more about it here `:h /\{-` and `:h perl-patterns`. Using `:sort` with a pattern means the text after the matched pattern will be used for the sorting. This regex is matching the second column, so the sort command will sort on everything after the second column. Another way to do this is `:sort /\ze\w\+(/`. Using the `\ze` to specify the end of the match can sometimes make it easier to reason about. See `:h /\ze` for more information.